# To check whether a set is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is the following set measurable:
$A=  V \in ([0,1]-\mathbb{Q})$ 
where $V$ is the Vitali set and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you defined Vitali set as a subset of $[0,1]$ then $V \cup \mathbb[[0,1]-{Q}]=[[0,1]-Q]\cup B$, where B is some countable set and as such Lebesgue measurable. As all the finite number of components of $A$ are measurable so is $A$.

Comment: How do we get the countable set B?

Comment: $A$ is in between $[0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$ and $[0,1]$, let $B:=A-([0,1]-\mathbb{Q})=V \cap \mathbb{Q}$ this set is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ and therefore it's countable.